# git - checking in changes not staged in current branch to another branch

Tags: git

I am not confident this has an easy solution, but I'll try.

I've been making quite some changes in the current branch, starting from a little idea I had. Now I realize this should have been going into a separate branch.

Can I create a new branch now and check that stuff into it?

E.g. I'd like all following changes from branch `current` into a new branch `experiment`

```
# On branch current
# Changes not staged for commit:
#....
#      modified: Gemfile
#      modified: Gemfile.lock
#      modified: app/controllers/site_controller.rb
#      modified: app/views/sites/_form.html.erb
#
# Untracked files:
#...
#      app/models/user.rb
#      #some more files
```

Comment: If you just create and checkout a new branch your changes should carry over and you can commit them there.

Comment: @ChrisHayes so simple...and it worked! please consider providing this as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check out a new branch with unstaged changes in your workspace, git will simply attempt to apply those changes to the new branch.

```
$ git branch myFeature
$ git checkout myFeature
M       Gemfile
M       Gemfile.lock
M       app/controllers/site_controller.rb
M       app/views/sites/_form.html.erb
Switched to branch 'myFeature'
```

You may have an issue if the changes fail to apply to the branch you're checking out, but in the case of creating a brand new branch, this will never be the case.